# I have a method that works in my MainActivity, but the same code does not work in other classes

Tags: android, mysql

I have a method that calls a php page to retrieve data from MySQL.  The method works just fine in my MainActivity class, but the exact same code does not work if I move the code into a different class.  Here is my Method:

```
 public void setRoundNumber() {
    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://brad.grublist.net/project/getRoundNumber.php");
        nameValuePairsRoundNumber = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairsRoundNumber.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventDate", GlobalClass.eventDate));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairsRoundNumber));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String json = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray roundNumber = jsonObj.getJSONArray("roundNumber");     
                    JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) roundNumber.get(0);
                    String roundNum = catObj.getString("roundNumber");
                    GlobalClass.roundNumber = roundNum;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing in my other classes to get this method to work there?  I have also tried making this a static method in my MainActivity and tried accessing it in other classes and have had no luck with that either.

Comment: Maybe because in your MainActivity you call setRoundNumber in a Asynctask and in other activities no.

Comment: at least you should find errors and post them here, or show how you call that function